# Convergence of the powers of a Markov transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, markov-process

I have a Markov matrix $$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0\\\frac{1}{4}&0&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\\frac{1}{8}&0&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\\frac{1}{16}&0&\frac{1}{16}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}\\0&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
and I want to show that the powers of $P$ converge. I can see numerically that $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}P^n=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\.8&0&0&0&0&.2\\.6&0&0&0&0&.4\\.4&0&0&0&0&.6\\.2&0&0&0&0&.8\\0&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
but are there any general results I can use to actually prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}P^n$ exists?

Comment: @A.S.  
You are right about the convergence, of course. But I don't think the term "irreducible" is quite right when there are absorbing states.

Comment: @Byron You are correct. How do you call a chain whose state space can't be separated into components w/no moves between them? (though in this problem, aperiodicity is enough for convergence).

Comment: Maybe useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58249/the-limit-of-matrices

Comment: This chain has three classes $C_1=\{1\}$ which is absorbing, $C_2=\{2,3,4,5\}$ which is transient and $C_3=\{6\}$ which is again absorbing. So, eventually you will land in one of $C_1$ or $C_3$ and remain there. So, the set of all invariant distributions is given by $π(1)=λ=1-π(6)$ for any $λ\in[0,1]$ and $π(x)=0$ else. So, I do not see how it converges to this matrix.

Comment: @Jimmy The matrix exactly satisfies your description.

Comment: @A.S. But then I would expect that the limit has zero in the rows that correspond to the transient states. Obviously I am missing something then...

Comment: @Jimmy It has zeros in those *columns*. Transpose you mental representation of a stochastic matrix. The one used here is customary for Markov Chains in math, though some rare applied people use your convention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the OP we restrict attention to Markov Chains with finite state space $\Bbb X=\{1,2,\dots,N\}$. There are two conditions (i) irreducibility and (ii) aperiodicity which determine the convergence of the transition matrices $A^n$. But firstly lets introduce some minimal (nowhere exhaustive) standard notation that is common in almost all textbook or references about Markov Chains (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)):

- Transition probabilities: $p^{(n)}_{ij}$ denotes the probability of going from state $i$ to state $j$ in $n$ time steps. In particular $p^{(1)}_{ij}$ or simply $p_ij$ is defined as $$p_{ij}=P(X_1=i \mid X_0=j)$$
- Stationary distribution: A probability vector $π$ that satisfies $π=πP$ is called a stationary distribution. To avoid a sloppy exposition I skip the details and let you read yourself about it.
- Hitting times/ probabilities: Let $T_1:=\inf\{n\ge 0: X_n=1\}$ be the first time that the chain will land in state $1$ and hence remain at it thereafter (as it is absorbing). Accordingly, define $$h^{1}_k:=\Bbb P(T_1<T_6\mid X_0=k)$$ to be the probability that the chain will be absorbed by state $T_1$ starting from state $k \in \mathbb X$.
- Irreducibility: *A Markov chain is said to be irreducible if its state space is a single communicating class; in other words, if it is possible to get to any state from any state.* This is not the case here, as your chain has $3$ communicating classes: $C_1=\{1\}, C_2=\{6\}$ which are closed (absorbing states) and $C_2=\{2,3,4,5\}$ which is open or transient.
- (A)periodicity: A state $i$ has period $k$ if any return to state $i$ must occur in multiples of $k$ time step. If $k=1$ then the state is called aperiodic. If $p_{ii}>0$ then state $i$ and hence all states in its communicating class are aperiodic. This is the case here for *all* states.

---

1. **Case 1: irreducible and aperiodic**. If a Markov Chain $(X_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ with finite state space is (i) irreducible and (ii) aperiodic, then $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} p_{ij}^n=π_j$$ (where I use the usual notation for the transition probabilities and the stationary distribution). So, the question is what happens when either/both of these conditions are violated:
2. **Case 2: irreducible and periodic**. If the chain has period $d$ then for every pair $i,j \in \Bbb X$ there exists $0\le r\le d-1$ such that $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}p_{ij}^{md+r}=dπ_j$$ and $p_{ij}=0$ for all $n$ such that $n\neq r \mod d$.
3. **Case 3: reducible**. In this case, $π$ is not uniquely defined. For example in the OP we have that any $λπ^1+(1-λ)π^6$ is a stationary distribution for the whole chain, with $π^1(k)=δ_{1k}$ and $π^6=δ_{6k}$ for any $k\in \Bbb X$. Still, he following holds $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}p_{ij}^n=h_i^Cπ_j$$ where $h_i^C$ denotes the hitting probability of the closed Class $C$ with $j\in C$, starting from state $i$. (This is the case in the OP, see calculations below).
4. **Case 3: reducible and periodic**. In this case, you only need to adjust Cases $2$ and $3$ to fit the description of any particular chain.

---

To obtain the limiting matrix in the given example computationally (and not only numerically as you have it), denote the state space of the chain with $\Bbb X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and let $h^{1}_k:=\Bbb P(T_1<T_6\mid X_0=k)$ be the probability that he chain will be absorbed by the absorbing state $1$ instead of $6$. Formally $T_1$ is defined as $T_1:=\inf\{n\ge 0:X_n=1\}$ and similarly $T_6$. Then, solving the following system \begin{align}h^{1}_1&=1\\[0.1cm]h^{1}_2&=\tfrac12h^{1}_1+\tfrac12h^{1}_3\\h^{1}_3&=\tfrac14h^{1}_1+\tfrac14h^{1}_3+\tfrac12h^{1}_4\\h^{1}_4&=\tfrac18h^{1}_1+\tfrac18h^{1}_3+\tfrac14h^{1}_4+\tfrac12h^{1}_5\\h^{1}_5&=\tfrac1{16}h^{1}_1+\tfrac1{16}h^{1}_3+\tfrac18h^{1}_4+\tfrac14h^{1}_5+\tfrac12h^{1}_6\\[0.1cm]h^{1}_6&=0\end{align} yields the first column of the limiting matrix as you have it, i.e. $$\left(h^{1}_1,h^{1}_2,h^{1}_3,h^{1}_4,h^{1}_5,h^{1}_6\right)=\frac1{10}(10,8,6,4,2,0)$$ Since the chain will eventually get absorbed by either state $1$ or state $6$ the last column of the limiting matrix follows by complementarity.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Could you please tell me where I can find a reference for the notation and terminology you're using, since I only have very limited familiarity with these ideas.

Comment: @MontyHall I gave you a reference in Wikipedia and copied some minimal notation here. I think you will find the same notation in every standard textbook about Markov Chain, so I do find a point in referencing a specific book. Just follow your lecture notes/ reference that your lecturer gave you! To fit the standard notation, I also changed the transition matrix from $A$ to $P$, hope this is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation of the terminology and notation, and the reference as well; it is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

This may be a problem where you should consider finding the singular value
decomposition. In particular, if you can find the eigenvalues and their
respective eigenvectors for this problem and degenerate $A = Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$,
where $\Lambda$ is the eigenvalue matrix and $Q$ is the matrix who's columns
are the eigenvectors of the respective $i$th eigenvalues. This way, we can
use some of the theorems related to eigenvalue decomposition to find that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A^n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
Q \Lambda^n Q^{-1},$$
and because $\Lambda$ is found to be a diagonal matrix, we only need to
calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda_i^n$ for each eigenvalue
$\lambda_i$.

Comment: Does this approach work for this matrix?